# subtracting two times in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with my code. I am trying to subtracting the two times but it give me an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'time.struct_time' and 'time.struct_time'
```

The error are jumping on this line:

```
diff = (end_dt - start_dt)
```

When I try this:

```
start = "09:35:23"
end = "10:23:00"
start_dt = time.strptime(start, '%H:%M:%S')
end_dt = time.strptime(end, '%H:%M:%S')
diff = (end_dt - start_dt)
```

Can you please help me how to fix the error that I am getting?

Comment: This is a lot better than your last attempt! Thank you for creating an actual [mcve] for us. Had you edited your original question to this standard I'd have happily reopened it.

Comment: Thank you martin, so do you know how to fix the error that i am getting?  i cant be able to find out how!

Comment: I do still have a question for you: what is the result for `start = "00:01:00"` and `end = "23:59:00"`? What about `start = "23:59:00"` and `end = "00:01:00"`? That's the midnight issue mentioned on the other question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i will create a if statement to see if the time is in midnight so you dont need to worry. Can you post the code for me to get the result when I use subtract the times?

Comment: MartijnPieters are you going to post the code or not?????????????

Comment: Sorry, I don't have infinite time available to me, and there was already a correct answer there.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime

start = "09:35:23"
end = "10:23:00"
start_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M:%S')
end_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M:%S')
diff = (end_dt - start_dt)
print(diff)
```

**Output**

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 2857)
```

This generates two `datetime` objects, `start_dt` and `end_dt`. When you subtract one from the other it returns a `timedelta`.

Comment: You do need to explain that this produces a `timedelta` object, and what you can do with that.

Comment: @lambo477 i cant use `datetime` module because i am using xbmc and it will only work with `time.strptime`. When you suggested me to use it will give me an error `TypeError: attribute of type 'NoneType' is not callable`

Comment: @David you are going to need to clarify these details in your question. `datetime` is a built-in Python module, so it is expected that you can use it...!

Comment: @David: `xbmc` uses Python, the full Python library should be available.

Comment: @David: if there really is such a constraint, *put that in your question*, but I'd first check to make sure you don't have a `datetime.py` module somewhere that masked the built-in module.

Comment: @David: I do indeed see [reports that XBMC breaks the `datetime` module](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=112916); that thread has work-arounds. Apply those to this answer and you'll be fine.

Comment: And what if I **already** have `time.struct_time` objects and wanna compare them? Can I do this **without** converting to string?